# Mongoose: Understanding Callbacks vs Async/Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to understand a callbacks in mongoose. I really just want to clarify my understanding so I can be sure I am on the right track.

I understanding using async/await to do queries in mongodb using mongoose. For example, the following code will get a user from my database, assuming my model "User" is set up correctly.

```
const getUser = async () => {
     const user = await User.find({username: "John"})
     return user
}
```

Here is my problem. I am working through the odin project and I have came across a section where callbacks are used instead of async/await. I have read some of the mongoose documentation regarding the matter without any luck.

Here is an example I am working with:

```
passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
        User.findOne({username: username}, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err)
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {message:"Incorrect Username"})
            }
            if (user.password !== password) {
                return done(null, false, {message: "Incorrect password"})
            }
            return done(null, user)
        })
    })
)
```

I understand most of what is going on here, but I do not understand how this is able to function without the use of async/await. I am looking specifically at the line:

```
User.findOne({username: username}, (err, user) => {callback})
```

My guess is that the database is queried, and if the user is found the data from the query is stored in the parameter "user."

If the query fails and no data is returned, then user becomes null and our err parameter will contain a message.

Is this correct?

Comment: `await` is syntax sugar. You can think of `s = await find()` as `find(s => {})` Your understanding is correct.

Comment: @sean-7777 Thank you so much I appreciate the clarification. I just hate moving forward from a topic without really getting what is going on. Thanks again!

Comment: What @sean-7777 is not entirely true. async/await is syntactic sugar over Promises but NOT callbacks. You can't just slap `await` to a function using callbacks and expect it to work. You need to create a new function which wraps the original function and returns a Promise, which is called promisifying.

Comment: Generally: The `async` keyword means *"The return value of this function is going to be a promise."* When you wrap an API that already produces promises (like Mongoose `.find()` does), then you can directly return that promise without changing function semantics. `const getUser  = async () => { return await Users.find(...) };` is exactly the same thing as `const getUser  = () => Users.find(...);`. Therefore, `return await` is useless fundamentally useless. Just `return` (a promise, or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple concept

```
async getUserList(){
  try{
     const users = User.findOne({username: username});
     return users;
  }catch(error){
    throw error;
  }
}
```

call function anywhere

`console.log(getUserList());`